# Inserir aresta num grafo

Tags: python, grafo

Estou a tentar inserir uma aresta num grafo. O problema consiste em representar uma linha de metro, considerando a informação existente em ficheiros csv. Criei as classes `Vertex`, `Edge`, `Station(Vertex)`, `Edge_Line(Edge)` e a `GraphList`.

```
Com este método, consigo inserir os vértices do grafo:
def create_stations(filename='lisbon.stations.csv'):
    stations = []
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as stations_info:
        station_info = csv.reader(stations_info, delimiter=',')
        # skip first line, which is just attribute names
        next(station_info)
        # empty list to hold stations

        # parse all the lines and create stations
        for row in station_info:
            #print(row[3],row[2])
            id = row[0]
            latitude = row[1]
            longitude = row[2]
            nome = row[3]
            # assign each attribute of Station based on line in file
            #(id, latitude, longitude, nome) = tuple(row)
            #create Station instance with those attributes
            newstation = Station(id, latitude, longitude, nome)
            #print(newstation)
            stations.append(newstation)
    return stations

map = GraphList()

def station_network():
    for station in create_stations():
        map.insert_vertex(station)
    return map
```

Criei este método para tentar obter as ligações:

```
def create_connections(filename = 'lisbon.connections.csv'):
    connections = []
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as conections_info:
        conection_info = csv.reader(conections_info, delimiter=',')
        next(conection_info)

        for row in conection_info:
            (origem, destino, linha) = tuple(row)
            connections.append(Edge_Line(origem, destino, linha))
    return connections
```

Contudo, quando tento criar as arestas, obtenho o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/sandr/PycharmProjects/teste6/main.py", line 282, in station_network
    map.insert_egde(connection._origem, connection.destination)
  File "C:/Users/sandr/PycharmProjects/teste6/main.py", line 217, in insert_egde
    self._outgoing[u].append(edge)
KeyError: '1'
```

Como é que posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Oi, a parte onde está acontecendo a linha onde ocorre o erro parece não estar no código que você listou, justamente a `insert_egde(()` mas creio que o problema aqui seja de se estar procurando a chave '1' no dicionário, que não existe. Se for isto, trocar `self._outgoing[u].append(edge)` por `self._outgoing.get(u, []).append(edge)` deve resolver.

Comment: Outra coisa, a função `map()` faz parte das funções internas do Python e não é uma boa ideia usá-la como nome de variável (`map = GraphList()`). -- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Correção, você precisa ter a chave criada antes então use `if not self._outgoing.get(u): self.__outgoing[u]=[]` antes do `self._outgoing[u].append(edge)` para criá-la e evitar o erro -- apenas fiz a substituição sem prestar muita atenção ao resto :-)

Comment: @GiovanniNunes, eu tenho um ficheiro csv que representa as ligações entre estações e a linha a que pertencem no formato (estação 1, estação 2, linha) - (1,2,1). Como é que posso associar esta chave ao nome de cada estação e assim criar as arestas respetivas? Tenho um outro ficheiro em que tenho o id da estação. Existe maneira de cruzar toda esta informação?

Comment: @GiovanniNunes obrigada pela dica da função map. Já alterei o nome :)

Comment: @GiovanniNunes os meus ficheiros csv têm a seguinte estrutura:
'lisbon.stations.csv' -> (id, latitude, longitude, nome) = (1, -9.3, 9.3, Lisboa)
'lisbon.connections.csv' -> (station 1, station 2, linha) = (1,2,1)
Como é que consigo associar a station 1 ao nome da estação cujo id é o 1 e inserir essa aresta?

Answer (score 0):

Baseado na descriçao do CSV que você passou e considerando que não sei o que será feito depois que arestas e vértices estiverem definidos, optei por uma abordagem com um menor número de classes:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from enum import Enum

class Line(Enum):
    AMARELA = 1
    AZUL = 2
    VERDE = 3
    VERMELHA = 4

@dataclass
class Edge:
    station: str
    lattitude: float
    longitude: float

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.station}"

@dataclass
class Vertex:
    source: Edge
    destination: Edge
    line: Line

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.source} -> {self.destination} (Linha {self.line.name})"
```

A primeira classe, `Line`, é uma [enumeração](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/search.html?q=dataclass&check_keywords=yes&area=default) e serve para deixar mais fácil a identificação das linhas e também redefini-las para os valores que estão no CSV. As classes `Edge` e `Vertex` usam [Data Classes](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=dataclass#module-dataclasses) para deixar o exemplo curto (cuida de criar o `__init__()` para mim).

Daí criei uma classe para juntar arestas e vértices:

```py
class Graph:
    edges = {}
    vertices = []

    def __init__(self, stations, connections):

        for station in stations:
            station_id, name, lattitude, longitude = station
            self.edges[station_id] = Edge(name, lattitude, longitude)

        for connection in connections:
            source, destination, line = connection
            self.vertices.append(
                Vertex(self.edges[source], self.edges[destination], line)
            )
```

Ela recebe a lista das estações (seguindo o modelo do CSV com "id", "nome", "latitude" e "longitude") e cria um dicionário onde a chave é o *id* da estação e  o valor uma instância da classe `Edge`.

Num segundo momento são adicionados os vértices (também seguindo o modelo do CSV com "origem", "destino" e "linha"). Como a chave do dicionário é o *id* da estação eu crio `Vertex` passando as instâncias de origem, destino (como o Python trabalha por referência não há replicação) e a linha em si.

E claro, a parte importante! (reduzi a lista de estações para não ficar extenso)

```py
stations = (
    (30, "Marquês de Pombal", 0.0, 0.0),
    (38, "Parque", 0.0, 0.0),
    (39, "Picoas", 0.0, 0.0),
    (41, "Praça de Espanha", 0.0, 0.0),
    (43, "Rato", 0.0, 0.0),
    (48, "S. Sebastião", 0.0, 0.0),
    (50, "Saldanha", 0.0, 0.0),
)

connections = (
    (41, 48, Line.AZUL),
    (48, 50, Line.VERMELHA),
    (48, 38, Line.AZUL),
    (38, 30, Line.AZUL),
    (30, 43, Line.AMARELA),
    (39, 30, Line.AMARELA),
)

my_graph = Graph(stations, connections)

for vertex in my_graph.vertices:
    print(vertex)
```

E o resultado:

```
Praça de Espanha -> S. Sebastião (Linha AZUL)
S. Sebastião -> Saldanha (Linha VERMELHA)
S. Sebastião -> Parque (Linha AZUL)
Parque -> Marquês de Pombal (Linha AZUL)
Marquês de Pombal -> Rato (Linha AMARELA)
Picoas -> Marquês de Pombal (Linha AMARELA)
```

Os métodos `__str__()` nas classes `Edge` e `Vertex` cuidam de formatar a saída delas para o `print()`.

Ah sim, você pode substituir "stations" e "connections" pelos teus CSV.